# After migration to SharePoint 2013, old Lists still have SharePoint 2010 look and feel

Tags: 2013, list, migration

I've and migrated SharePoint environment (2010 > 2013). Everything is working fine, except the look and feel on old lists migrated from SharePoint 2010.

Dialogs still open in a modal and I have the old "Add new item" button with the green + on the bottom of the list instead of the new modern ui style blue one on the top.

How can I update the list to look like a list directly created in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Is site fully upgraded to the sharepoint 2013?

Comment: Yes. Everything has 2013 style applied. Only old lists remain with the old + button at  the bottom.

Comment: Did not fix my problem. tried the above mentioned steps. ANy help, highly appreciated.

Comment: Solution from yan.kun0567 to set the JSLink to clienttemplates.js solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found an answer. Their is a property called JSLink on the list views. Lists using the new style having the value clienttemplate.js.

As soon as I set this property on my old view, the style changed into the new one. Seems like the new look is basing purely on a client side transformation... MICROSOFT!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I migrated, most noticeably with image libraries not using the new thumbnail view. I fixed it by changing the view settings. My example is for an image library but hopefully it fixes the issue for your list too.

Here are the steps:

1. From the library, click on the Library tab
2. Click "Modify View"
3. Scroll way down to "Style" and expand it
4. Choose "Default"
5. Click Ok

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Default was already selected. Tried to change forth an back, without success.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve faced the same issue and nailed it down to the [InlineEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.inlineedit.aspx)-Property of `SPView`. Apparently InlineEdit is not supported in 2013 and there is no option so reset/remove it via UI.

I use a PowerShell script to set this property to `$null` on each view in every list after a site collection has been upgraded to 2013 look and feel:

```
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    foreach ($list in $web.Lists)
    {
        foreach ($view in $list.Views)
        {
            if ($view.InlineEdit -eq "TRUE") # really a string
            {
                $view.InlineEdit = $null
                $view.Update()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Setting `InlineEdit = "false"` as mentioned in the MSDN article did not work as expected, but setting to `$null` did.

Subsequently, the list and the view behaves "2013-like".

Comment: Didn't solved the problem for me :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: What's the value of `$view.InlineEdit` in your broken list or view? I'm just curious :)

Comment: It has been false, now its null.